# Donet test in Azure DevOps gets stuck after TestManagement.Server.TriggerCoverageMergeJob is on

Tags: .net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In Azure DevOps I have a local agent running `dotnet test` in a pipeline on my code. It used to work before my holiday, but something has changed and causes this pipeline to hang for 60 minutes and then kill itself.

I enabled the debug mode, but can only see `TestManagement.Server.TriggerCoverageMergeJob` and then nothing.

Does someone here know what to do?

The code is .NET5 based and uses a few Selenium Tests on both Chrome and Firefox. According to the run report this part works fine and all tests passed.
Agent is Windows 10 Enterprise, running agent version 2.198.3 (=latest)

```
##[debug]File uploaded successsfully on LogStore svc-testautomation_RDP-DEVEL04_2022-02-09_10_09_41.trx
Published Test Run : URL/_TestManagement/Runs?runId=73850&_a=runCharts
##[debug]Leaving PublishToNewTestRunPerTestResultFileAsync
##[debug]TestManagement.PTR.CalculateTestRunSummary is on
##[debug]RESOURCE_URIS:
##[debug]Setting task variable METADATA_dd056f4a-e5ec-4040-b2dd-76c58de85acd: {"name":"f7e05d93-4f75-4d21-81b6-a7f562d79972","resourceUris":[],"metadata":{"description":"","relatedUrls":[{"url":"URL/_build/results?buildId=13313","label":"pipeline-url"}],"humanReadableName":"Test Results from Publish Test Results utility","serializedPayload":"{\"testId\":\"PublishTestResults\",\"testTool\":\"VSTest\",\"testResultAttestation\":{\"total\":20,\"failed\":0,\"passed\":19,\"skipped\":0},\"testDurationSeconds\":0.0,\"testPassPercentage\":\"95\",\"relatedUrls\":[{\"url\":\"URL/_build/results?buildId=13313\",\"label\":\"pipeline-url\"}]}"}} 
##[debug]TestManagement.Agent.PTR.EnableFlakyCheck is on
##[debug]TestManagement.Server.TriggerCoverageMergeJob is on
```

Pipeline template:

```
jobs:
- job: build
  displayName: Build and validate
  steps:
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'dotnet restore'
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        projects: '${{ parameters.projectFile }}'
        feedsToUse: 'select'
        vstsFeed: '${{ parameters.vstsFeed }}'

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'dotnet build'
      inputs:
        command: 'build'
        projects: '${{ parameters.projectFile }}'
        arguments: '--configuration ${{ parameters.configuration }}'

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'dotnet test'
      inputs:
        command: test
        projects: '${{ parameters.projectFile }}'
        arguments: '--configuration ${{ parameters.configuration }}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was not with the pipeline itself. It was running UI Tests that started chromedriver and a BrowserStackLocal.exe. If a test failed these executables where not terminated causing the pipeline to wait untill these services were closed. That did never happen, resulting in a long wait and abort after 60 minutes.